# Loading jasperreports' .jrxml files

Tags: java, jasper-reports

In my project I have stored .jrxml files in a package called com/bio/ofm/mnu/views/reports/jasperReports/
When I try to load a .jrxml I get following error,

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/bio/ofm/mnu/views/reports/jasperReports/repAuditReport.jrxml (No such file or directory)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:174)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:154)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:146)
        at com.bio.ofm.mnu.views.panels.RepAuditReport$2.run(RepAuditReport.java:87)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/bio/ofm/mnu/views/reports/jasperReports/repAuditReport.jrxml (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:169)
        ... 4 more
```

This is how I load the file,

```
String fileName = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/bio/ofm/mnu/views/reports/jasperReports/repAuditReport.jrxml").getFile();    

   JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("com/bio/ofm/mnu/views/reports/jasperReports/repAuditReport.jrxml");
```

please help

Comment: You should check whether the file is in the output folder (where your class files in), not your source folder.

Comment: :@Rangi Lin - I've put those .jrxml in a package as mentioned

Comment: Are you using it with webapp??
If yes than which (i.e. spring,etc.)? 
My guess is that the file is not in your classpath or if its your app doesnt know abt it.!

Answer (score 3):

When loading the file as a stream like below it worked,

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/bio/ofm/mnu/views/reports/jasperReports/repAuditReport.jrxml");

JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(in);
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm compiling my reports like that:

```
ByteArrayInputStream is = MyRenderer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("anytemplate.jrxml");

JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(is);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```